# Filling out missing information by grouping in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a sample dataset below:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                 gender = c("male",NA,"female","female",NA, "female"))

> df
  id gender
1  1   male
2  1   <NA>
3  2 female
4  2 female
5  3   <NA>
6  3 female
```

By grouping the same `id`s, some rows are missing. What I would like to do is to fill those missing cells based on the existing information.

SO the desired output would be:

```
> df
  id gender
1  1   male
2  1   male
3  2 female
4  2 female
5  3 female
6  3 female
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::group_by` and `tidyr::fill` e.g.:

```
df |>
  dplyr::group_by(id) |>
  tidyr::fill(gender, .direction = "updown")
```